# Have multiple GET requests and call state setter once they have all completed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to render a list of favorite movies based on signed-in user's list.The flow is following:

1. I have ID of favorited movies in the firebase DTB for each user
2. User visits the "favorited" page and the collection of favorited movies is updated
3. Then the API call for movieDB is called for each movie to render movie list

Unfortunately I was able to update the array of objects only via push, which resulted in calling `setContent(items)` for every item which means that `content` variable exists even with 1st iteration, leaving the option to render the "trending" `div` as value is truth not rendering full content.

How can I either refactor the `useEffect`? Change the render conditions for "Trending" to be sure, that all values in `content` var are finished updating via API?

```js
const Favorite = () => {
  const { user } = useAuthContext();
  const { documents: movies } = useCollection("favMovies", ["uid", "==", user.uid]); // only fetch movies for loged user

  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [content, setContent] = useState([]);
  const [numOfPages, setNumOfPages] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const items = [];

    movies &&
      movies.forEach(async (movie) => {
        try {
          const response = await axios.get(
            `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/${movie.mediaType}/${movie.id}?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}&language=en-US`
          );
          items.push(response.data);
          setContent(items);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      });
  }, [movies]);

  return (
    <div>
      <span className="pageTitle">Trending</span>

      <div className="trending">
        {content &&
          content.map((con) => (
            <SingleContent
              key={con.id}
              id={con.id}
              poster={con.poster_path}
              title={con.title || con.name}
              date={con.first_air_date || con.release_date}
              mediaType={con.media_type}
              voteAverage={con.vote_average}
            />
          ))}
      </div>

      <CustomPagination setPage={setPage} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Favorite;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overcome your problem by using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). For that change your `useEffect` code to:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const fectchMovies = async () => {
    if (!movies) return;
    try {
      const promises = movies.map((movie) =>
        axios.get(
          `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/${movie.mediaType}/${movie.id}?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}&language=en-US`
        )
      );
      const content = await Promise.all(promises);
      setContent(content.map(c => c.data));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
  fectchMovies();
}, [movies]);
```